# Playing a 7-string guitar song on a 6-string guitar

Tags: guitar, chords, strings

In this video

John Petrucci tries to explain how a guy is doing a cover of one of his 7-string songs using a 6-string guitar, but I don't really understand what he is saying. Anybody can help?

Answer (score 6):

He's describing the effect that happens when you play a perfect fourth with a distorted guitar. Distortion intensifies the intermodulation effect between the two strings to produce sum-tones and difference-tones.

```
$4.5.$5.5  $4.5.$5.5.$6.3    $4.6.$5.6  $4.6.$5.6.$6.4 
$4.7.$5.7  $4.7.$5.7.$6.5
```

Basically playing the *partial* power-chord makes it sound like a full power-chord.

Comment: So, is a *partial power chord* P4, and a *power chord* P5? Or is *partial* using only two strings? (Not seen video).

Comment: It's a P4 which implies the root beneath, with distortion it actually produces the sub-harmonic.